# CSS flip card - how do I make the front smaller than the back

Tags: css, overflow, flip

I have a flip card, which I've built using CSS. It flips perfectly, but I'd like to make the front side of the card smaller than the back. I've tried adjusting the heights, but I'm running into issues with overflow, etc. I tried to Google this but only found one site; they didn't quite cover what I need.

So my question is how do I make the front shorter than the back, with the back having consistent background color and overflow that fully shows and doesn't leave the background.

Here is a great website that does just what I'd like:
https://businessexpress.maryland.gov/

Please be sure to look at that website above. It really shows what I mean. I looked at their code but I can't figure out what to do.

I have a fiddle here, with my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/1ehtw5L4/

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="flip-cards">
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <h2 class="front-title">Prepare Your Business</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h2>Content</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 19%;
  /* change the below */
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner, .flip-card:active .flip-card-inner, .flip-card:focus .flip-card-inner, .flip-card:focus-within .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #008CCC;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  color: black;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  /* change the below */
  height: 400px;
}

.flip-card-back ul {
  padding-left:1em;
  padding-right:1em;
  list-style-type:none;
}

.flip-card-back li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.flip-card-back li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.flip-card-back h2 {
  text-align:center;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  padding-top:0.6em;
  padding-bottom:0.6em;
}

.flip-card-back h2 a, .flip-card-back h2 a:visited {
  color:white;
}

.flip-card-back a {
  display:block;
}

.front-title {
  padding-top:0.6em;
  padding-bottom:0.6em;
}

.flip-cards {
  display:flex;
}

.sbr-intro {
  margin-bottom:1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `height: auto;` to  `.flip-card-front`.

I also added `pointer-events: none;` to `.flip-card` and added `pointer-events: auto;` to `.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back` for hover bug.

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 19%;
  /* change the below */
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner,
.flip-card:active .flip-card-inner,
.flip-card:focus .flip-card-inner,
.flip-card:focus-within .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: auto;
}


/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #008CCC;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
  color: black;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  /* change the below */
  height: 400px;
}

.flip-card-back ul {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.flip-card-back li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.flip-card-back li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.flip-card-back h2 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 0.6em;
  padding-bottom: 0.6em;
}

.flip-card-back h2 a,
.flip-card-back h2 a:visited {
  color: white;
}

.flip-card-back a {
  display: block;
}

.front-title {
  padding-top: 0.6em;
  padding-bottom: 0.6em;
}

.flip-cards {
  display: flex;
}

.sbr-intro {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-cards">
  <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <h2 class="front-title">Prepare Your Business</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <h2>Content</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how I can make the back go upwards, like in the example website https://businessexpress.maryland.gov/

Comment: @Mark add `bottom:0;` to `flip-card-front`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set width and height after flipping as well if you want different behavior.

I added attributes to following selector:

```
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner, .flip-card:active .flip-card-inner, .flip-card:focus .flip-card-inner, .flip-card:focus-within .flip-card-inner
```

Try the following CSS:

```
.flip-card {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 19%;
    /* change the below */
    height: 120px;
    margin: auto;
    perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-card-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner, .flip-card:active .flip-card-inner, .flip-card:focus .flip-card-inner, .flip-card:focus-within .flip-card-inner {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.flip-card-front {
    background-color: #008CCC;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.flip-card-back {
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
    color: black;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    /* change the below */
    height: 400px;
}

.flip-card-back ul {
    padding-left:1em;
    padding-right:1em;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.flip-card-back li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.flip-card-back li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.flip-card-back h2 {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    padding-top:0.6em;
    padding-bottom:0.6em;
}

.flip-card-back h2 a, .flip-card-back h2 a:visited {
    color:white;
}

.flip-card-back a {
    display:block;
}

.front-title {
    padding-top:0.6em;
    padding-bottom:0.6em;
}

.flip-cards {
    display:flex;
}

.sbr-intro {
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
```